# Can I return a List with no type?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to read information from a file to upsert information on a CustomObject. This works for several objects so the process would be like this:

1. The user selects from a PickList the CustomObject that wil be affected by the upsert
2. The file containing the data is uploaded
3. The contents of the file are displayed
4. On user confirmation the data is upserted to the platform

My problem is between number 2 and 3. On the Visualforce, I'm displaying the data read from the file and in the controller I have a `List` from where the view is populated. But the problem is that the `List` has to be of the type of the selected CustomObject. For example if the user selects the object Box, the List should be defined as `List<Box>` but if the user selects the object Car, the List then should be `List<Car>`.

My idea is to build a method that returns the right list based on the user selection and save that to the `List` variable that is bounded to the view but I don't know how to declare it.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: You can use a list of dynamic sObjects - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm

Comment: @BorisBachovski it gives me this error: `Illegal assignment from List<Box> to List<SObject>`

Comment: @CarlosJiménez It sounds like you need to type cast the assignment `list<sObject> solist = (list<sObject>) myBoxListVariable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `list<Object>` and add sObjects, primitive data types, custom defined classes, collections, or anything you want to it.

```
list<Object> olist = new list<Object>();
olist.add(new Account());
olist.add('string');
olist.add(new list<String>());
olist.add(new WrapperClass());
system.debug(olist);
```

---

Although the title of your question asks for a list that will accept any type, based on what you are trying to build, the sObject type could be very useful since a list of sObjects can be used directly in the database manipulation methods:

```
String InputData = '{"name":"recordName"}';
String SelectedSObjectType = 'Account';

Type t = Type.forName(SelectedSObjectType);

list<sObject> solist = new list<sObject>();
sObject so = (sObject) JSON.deserialize(InputData,t);
solist.add(so);

Database.insert(solist);
```

Comment: You can get stronger typing but stay generic with `List<SObject>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @martín. I have implemented the `List<SObject>` and now I can save any type of data on that `List` now my problem comes when I'm trying to display the information on the Visualforce page. I get the error `Wrong type for attribute <c:row_record="row">. Expected Box__c, found sObject`

Comment: @CarlosJiménez You are probably going to want to use [dynamic visualforce bindings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf.htm), where your visual force page will access fields on your sObject like this:  `<apex:outputField value="{!so['name']}" />`.